# Extracting text from a PDF file

Tags: c#, java, .net, ikvm

I'm using PDFBox for a C# .NET project. and I'm getting a "TypeInitializationException" (The type initializer for 'java.lang.Throwable' threw an exception.) when executing the following block of code :

```
  FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\1.pdf",FileMode.Open);

  //retrieve the pdf bytes from the stream.
  byte[] pdfbytes=new byte[65000];

  stream.Read(pdfbytes, 0, 65000);

 //get the pdf file bytes.
 allbytes = pdfbytes;

 //create a stream from the file bytes.
 java.io.InputStream ins = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(allbytes);
 string txt;

 //load the doc
 PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(ins);
 PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

 //retrieve the pdf doc's text
 txt = stripper.getText(doc);
 doc.close();
```

the exception occurs at the 3rd statement :

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(ins);
```

What can I do to solve this ?

This is the stack trace :

```
           at java.lang.Throwable.__<map>(Exception , Boolean )
   at org.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse()
   at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(InputStream input, RandomAccess scratchFile)
   at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(InputStream input)
   at At.At.ExtractTextFromPDF(InputStream fileStream) in
 C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AtProject\Att\At.cs:line 61
```

Inner Exception of the InnerException :

- InnerException  {"Could not load file or assembly 'IKVM.Runtime, Version=0.30.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"IKVM.Runtime, Version=0.30.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58"}    System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}

OK, I solved the previous problem by copying some .dll files of the PDFBox to my bin folder. but now I'm getting this error : expected='/' actual='.'--1 org.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream@283d742

Are there any alternatives to using PDFBox ? is there any other reliable library out there I can use to extract text from pdf files.

Comment: PDFBox is a Java library, and your code looks like Java. Where's C# involved?

Comment: What's the inner exception of the `TypeInitializationException`?

Comment: Bit confused; you say its C#, but its Java.

And in Java strings are of type "String" yet you use "string"

Comment: the inner exceptions states : "The type initializer for 'java.lang.Throwable' threw an exception."

Comment: So... are you saying that this is c# code and it's throwing a Java type initializer exception? Or is it Java code and you're trying to use it like c#, in which case it would probably throw exceptions like crazy?

Comment: This is C# code and I'm calling classes from the java.io namespace that comes with the PDFBox library.

Comment: PDFBox apparently has a .NET version based on IKVM http://incubator.apache.org/pdfbox/userguide/dot_net.html

Comment: What's the inner exception of the inner exception?

Comment: @dtb inner exception of the inner exception : -  InnerException {"Could not load file or assembly 'IKVM.Runtime, Version=0.30.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"IKVM.Runtime, Version=0.30.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58"} System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}

Comment: OK, I solved the previous problem by copying some .dll files of the PDFBox to my bin folder. but now I'm getting this error :

expected='/' actual='.'--1 org.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream@283d742

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you missing some library for PDFBox. You need:

- IKVM.GNU.Classpath.dll
- PDFBox-X.X.X.dll
- FontBox-X.X.X-dev.dll
- IKVM.Runtime.dll

Read this topic [Read from a PDF file using C#](http://studentclub.ro/lucians_weblog/archive/2007/03/22/read-from-a-pdf-file-using-c.aspx). You can find the discussion of similar problem in comments of this topic.

Comment: thanks for your response Sasha.
I've already solved this problem though.
I'm now facing another one : "expected='/' actual='.'--1 org.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream@283d742". it seems this doesn't happen with all pdf files, but with some.

Comment: It look like something wrong with your pdf file. Is it well formated? Can you post link to it, I will try to test this situation?

Comment: I'm in a WCF client/WCF service scenario here. so, I send a file by streaming to the WCF Service and then try to extract text from it as text is received. maybe that's where the problem lies.

Comment: I don’t think so. Try to compare file before send and after... And look at file format, it look like something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the versions of the DLL files were the culprits.
Go to http://www.netlikon.de/docs/PDFBox-0.7.2/bin/?C=M;O=A and download the following files:

- IKVM.Runtime.dll
- IKVM.GNU.Classpath.dll
- PDFBox-0.7.2.dll

Then copy them into the root of your Visual Studio project. Right click the project and add reference, find all 3 and add them.

Finally here's the code I used to parse the PDF into Text

C#

```
private static string TransformPdfToText(string SourceFile)
{
string content = "";
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
doc.close();
doc = PDDocument.load(SourceFile);

try
{
content = stripper.getText(doc);
doc.close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
doc.close();
}
return content;
}
```

Visual Basic

```
Private Function parseUsingPDFBox(ByVal filename As String) As String
    LogFile(" Attempting to parse file: " & filename)
    Dim doc As PDDocument = New PDDocument()
    Dim stripper As PDFTextStripper = New PDFTextStripper()
    doc.close()
    doc = PDDocument.load(filename)

    Dim content As String = "empty"
    Try
        content = stripper.getText(doc)
        doc.close()
    Catch ex As Exception
         LogFile(" Error parsing file: " & filename & vbcrlf & ex.Message)
    Finally
        doc.close()
    End Try
    Return content
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

had a similar problem but not with C++ but VisualBasic/VisualStudio; the missing dll is "commons-logging.dll"; after adding this dll to the bin-directory everything worked find